# WP meta_query passing an array for an IN comparison

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a string that I want to separate into an array and then pass to the value of a meta_query and then pass with the IN operator.

For example:

```
$my_string = "San Francisco, CA 94111";
```

And then I was thinking I would do this:

```
$my_string = (explode(',',$my_string));
```

And then in my meta_query:

```
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'login_email',
        'value' => $my_string,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
```

This doesn't seem to work. And I wonder if it is how the array is written with keys and passed to the value operator.

For example:

```
Array ( [0] => san francisco [1] => ca 94111 )
```

vs

In the Wordpress documentation it wants something like:

```
array( 3, 4 ),
```

Beyond what I am working on now, I thing it would be useful to be able to do something like this for a meta_query.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: have you check the data saved against `meta key 'login_email'` ? , try search in `wp_postmeta` table by `login_email`

Comment: Could you be more specific on what "doesn't seem to work"?